# jQuery setInterval with fadeIn, fadeOut bug in chrome?

Tags: jquery, slider, fadein, fadeout, setinterval

I'm going crazy trying to figure this out.  On the homepage of my site I have a slider that currently has four items (the html is created dynamically, so this solution has to work for any number of items).  These items are positioned absolutely on top of each other.  The script can do two things:

1) When clicking on a slider-nav-item (which is a anchor link), the current nav item fades out, and the new one fades in (cross-fades).

2) If the user does not click on any nav items, the slider will automatically progress to the next item.

My problem is only occurring in Chrome when I try to use setInterval.  When I do this, the cross fading does not work, and the outgoing container fades out to white, and then the container coming in just abruptly appears (no fading).

Here is my code.  Hoping for some ideas, because I've tried everything!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.slider-item:first').show();
    jQuery('.slider-nav-item').click(function () { 


        if (!jQuery(this).hasClass("activeSlide")) {


            clearInterval(s);
            s = setInterval ( "nextSlide()", 6000 );

            currentSlider = jQuery(this).attr("rel");

            jQuery('#slider .slider-item').fadeOut(1200);
            jQuery('#slider .slider-item:nth-child('+ currentSlider+')').fadeIn(1200);

            jQuery('.slider-nav-item').removeClass("activeSlide"); 
            jQuery(this).addClass("activeSlide");

        }

        return false;
     });

    var s = setInterval ( "nextSlide()", 6000 );


});


function nextSlide (){

    var max = jQuery('#slider-nav .slider-nav-item').length;

    var currentSlider = jQuery('.activeSlide').attr("rel");

    if (currentSlider == max) {

        jQuery('#slider .slider-item:nth-child('+currentSlider+')').fadeOut(1200);
        jQuery('#slider .slider-item:first').fadeIn(1200);

        jQuery('.slider-nav-item').removeClass("activeSlide"); 
        jQuery('.slider-nav-item:first').addClass("activeSlide");

    } else {

        var temp = parseInt(currentSlider) + 1;

        jQuery('#slider .slider-item:nth-child('+currentSlider+')').fadeOut(1200);
        jQuery('#slider .slider-item:nth-child('+temp+')').fadeIn(1200);

        jQuery('.slider-nav-item').removeClass("activeSlide"); 
        jQuery('#slider-nav .slider-nav-item:nth-child('+temp+')').addClass("activeSlide");

    }

}
```

Comment: You might consider making a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that there's a live example to play with.

Answer (score 2):

This won't fix the problem (maybe?)

```
var s = setInterval ( "nextSlide()", 6000 );
```

should be (best practice)

```
setInterval ( function(){
  nextSlide();
}, 6000 );
```

Also why not just use a plugin? http://css-tricks.com/3412-anythingslider-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with jQuery cross-fades where elements would abruptly appear exactly as you describe when the HTML wasn't valid. Run the page through a validator and correct any syntax issues, and see if the issue remains.

I've had several issues like this. jQuery seems to have a strong preference for valid HTML.